# generics compilation error: type argument is not within bounds of type-variable S

Tags: java, generics

Here's a simplified version of the object model that I am working on.

```
public class GenericsTest {
    public interface FooInterface {
        public void foo();
    }
    public class Bar implements FooInterface {
        public void foo() {}
    }
    public interface GenericInterface <T> {
        public T func1();
    }
    public class Service implements GenericInterface<Bar> {
        @Override
        public Bar func1() {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public class GenericBar <S extends GenericInterface<FooInterface>> {
        public S s;
        public GenericBar() {}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericBar<Service> serviceGenericBar;  // <-- compilation error at this line

      <... more code ...>
    }

}
```

Compiler Error: `type argument GenericsTest.Service is not within bounds of type-variable S`

IDE (intellij) shows some more details on the error: `Type parameter 'GenericsTest.Service' is not within its bound; should implement GenericsTest.GenericInterface<GenericTests.FooInterface>`

`Service` class is implementing the GenericInterface. I have looked at few other SO questions with the same error but they don't offer clues for this particular scenario. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Share the GenericBar implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is exactly what two compilers have told you: type `Service` is not within the bounds that type `GenericBar` requires of its type parameter, `S`.  Specifically, `GenericBar` requires the `S` parameter of its realizations to be bound to a type that extends `GenericInterface<FooInterface>`.  `Service` does not satisfy that requirement.

`Service` implements `GenericInterface<Bar>`, which is neither `GenericInterface<FooInterface>` nor an extension of that type, the fact that `Bar` implements `FooInterface` notwithstanding.  You cannot assign a `List<String>` to a variable of type `List<Object>`, either, for basically the same reason.

You can resolve the compilation error by modifying the definition of class `GenericBar` like so:

```
public class GenericBar <S extends GenericInterface<? extends FooInterface>> {
    public S s;
    public GenericBar() {}
}
```

Whether this is what you actually *want* to use is an entirely different question, which only you can answer.

Comment: Yes I need the `Service` class to be only responsible for `Bar` type.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you change Service to implement GenericInterface the code would compile.

```
public class Service implements GenericInterface<FooInterface> {
    @Override
    public Bar func1() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer to limit Service to base only on Bar you could change GenericBar so it will become more generic:

```
public class Service implements GenericInterface<Bar> {
    @Override
    public Bar func1() {
        return null;
    }
}

public class GenericBar<S extends GenericInterface<? extends FooInterface>> {
    public S s;

    public GenericBar() {
    }
}
```